# QEMU hostfwd works only for some ports

Tags: qemu, portforwarding

I compiled `qemu-system-x86_64` on aarch64 host, and was able to run a x86_64 guest with a command like

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4096 -drive file=vmimage.qcow2,if=virtio \
           -boot once=c,menu=on -net nic,model=virtio-net-pci \
           -net user,hostfwd=tcp::8080-:80,hostfwd=tcp::22222-:22
```

I could `ssh` into the guest using

```
ssh -p22222 user@localhost
```

Meanwhile, port 80 was not forwarded successfully.

For debugging, I used `nc` to listen to port 80 inside the guest

```
nc -l 80
```

Then in the host, I connected to the forwarded port

```
nc localhost 8080
```

However, it was unable to connect to guest `nc` .

I tried the monitor interface. When the host `nc` command is executed, `info usernet` shows following:

```
(qemu) info usernet
Hub 0 (#net162):
  Protocol[State]    FD  Source Address  Port   Dest. Address  Port RecvQ SendQ
  TCP[SYN_SENT]      33       127.0.0.1  8080       10.0.2.15    80     0     0
  TCP[ESTABLISHED]   21       127.0.0.1 22222       10.0.2.15    22     0     0
  TCP[HOST_FORWARD]  12               *  8080       10.0.2.15    80     0     0
  TCP[HOST_FORWARD]  11               * 22222       10.0.2.15    22     0     0
...
```

I believe the `SYN_SENT` (FD 33) corresponded to the host `nc` command, and this matched the `HOST_FORWARD` line (FD 12). However, it never became `ESTABLISHED`. And a few seconds later, `nc` died with `Connection reset by peer.` , and the FD 33 line disappeared.

If I `nc localhost 22222`, I can see the OpenSSH banner.

So it seems only port 22 forwarded. Any idea about the cause or how to debug?

Both host and guest had no **<del>firewall</del>`iptables`** configured, and SELinux is permissive.

Thanks

**Edit:**

As a temporary workaround, I configured a second nic, and used port 22 of the new interface for forwarding my service. I also switch to the newer `-nic` option, but `hostfwd` still worked for port 22 only.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4096 -drive file=vmimage.qcow2,if=virtio \
                   -boot once=c,menu=on \
                   -nic user,model=virtio-net-pci,hostfwd=tcp::60022-:22 \
                   -nic user,model=virtio-net-pci,net=10.0.3.0/24,hostfwd=tcp::8080-10.0.3.15:22
```

To forward successfully, I also need to

- Configure `sshd` to listen to port 22 the first nic only.
- Configure my service to listen to port 22 of the second nic.
- Configure the second nic to use a different network. Otherwise, both nics were assigned the same IP (10.0.2.15. I may better hardcode the IP for both nics.)

Comment: (May not work, I guess)Ports lower than 1024 are restricted by Linux.Are you root?

Comment: @AlanCui ,  Yes, I have root in both host and guest.
Note that for both ports in my question, I am forwarding between a (guest) privileged port and a (host) unprivileged port. So the situation of the 2 ports should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually about firewall. My VM (based on Oracle Linux 8.5 on [Oracle Linux VM Templates](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-templates.html)) actually had firewall rules in both `iptables` and `nft`. After disabling both `iptables` and `nft`, the port forward worked.